# Android App is crashing after several hours

Tags: android, crash

I have created an android application. It is running pretty good. But I am facing a problem. I have searched a lot but wasn't able to find the proper answer.

The problem is my application crashes when I open it after several hours like (After 3-4 hours). If i restart the application, it goes well. Otherwise it crashes. My code is:

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar bar=getSupportActionBar();
    bar.hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);        
    buttonCount=0;

    Button buttonLoc=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLocation);
    buttonLoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i=new Intent(DashboardActivity.this,SearchMaps.class);  
            int s=Landingpage.hospital_list.size();
            if(s!=0)
                {
                startActivity(i);
                }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();

        }
    });



    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonHosp);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i=new Intent(DashboardActivity.this,DoctorsActivity.class);
            int s=Landingpage.hospital_list.size();
            if(s!=0)
                {
                startActivity(i);
                }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            finish();
        }
    });


    buttonDoctors=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonDoctor);
    buttonDoctors.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i=new Intent(DashboardActivity.this,Search_doctors.class);
            int s=Landingpage.hospital_list.size();
            if(s!=0)
                {
                startActivity(i);
                }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            finish();

        }
    });


    buttontime=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttontime);
    buttontime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i=new Intent(DashboardActivity.this,SearchingByTime.class);
            int s=Landingpage.hospital_list.size();
            if(s!=0)
                {
                startActivity(i);
                }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();

        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);  
    return true;
}
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    buttonCount=0;
    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonHosp);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i=new Intent(DashboardActivity.this,DoctorsActivity.class);

            startActivity(i);

        }
    });


    buttonDoctors=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonDoctor);
    buttonDoctors.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i=new Intent(DashboardActivity.this,Search_doctors.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }
    });
    buttontime=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttontime);
    buttontime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i=new Intent(DashboardActivity.this,SearchingByTime.class);

            int s=Landingpage.hospital_list.size();
            if(s!=0)
                {
                startActivity(i);
                }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });


}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.help) {
        onHelp();
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.About) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("About Us")
        .setMessage("DocDig is an app that lets you find doctors in Islamabad "
                + "\n\n\n Sponsored By Code for Pakistan")
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", null).setInverseBackgroundForced(true).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void onHelp() {
       new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Help")
               .setMessage("DocDig is an app that lets you find doctors in Islamabad "
                    + "through following options..\n\n"
                    + "1. Search By Doctor --  In this option you would enter the Hospital name and "
                    + "the name of the doctor and the gender and the details of that doctor would be shown\n\n"
                    + "2. Search By Time -- You would select the hospital name, speciality, gender and the required date and time "
                    + "and all the doctors of that category will be shown\n\n"
                    + "3. Search By Hospital -- In this option, you would enter the hospital name, speciality and gender and the "
                    + "list of doctors would be shown")
               .setPositiveButton("Okay, Got it", null).show();
   }

public Animation inFromRightAnimation()
{
    Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    inFromRight.setDuration(240);
    inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return inFromRight;
}
public Animation outToRightAnimation()
{
    Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    outtoLeft.setDuration(240);
    outtoLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return outtoLeft;
}

public void onBackPressed()
{
    if(buttonCount >= 1)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        //finish();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press the back button once again to close the application.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        buttonCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen logcat, Whats the error ?

Comment: What is hospital_list? How you are setting it?

Comment: Yes I am setting it in a previous activity. 
No there is no error visible in logcat because the error comes when the application remains idle in background for 3-4 hours.